# Magento 1.6.2 Bestseller products not working

Tags: magento

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addOrderedQty()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description', 'description'))
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->setPageSize(4)
->setCurPage(1)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->load();
```

Bestsellers code not working in Magento 1.6.2. The collection is not even filtered by store.

`Zend_Debug::dump($storeId)`; gives me `string '2' (length=1)` but I can not execute `Zend_Debug::dump($products->getSelect());` because it gives me an error like `There has been and error processing your request` and it give s me the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty, order_items.name AS order_items_name, order_items.product_id AS entity_id, e.entity_type_id, e.attribute_set_id, e.type_id, e.sku, e.has_options, e.required_options, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.name, e.price, e.small_image, e.short_description FROM tp_sales_flat_order_item AS order_items INNER JOIN tp_sales_flat_order AS order ON order.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND order.state <> 'cancelled' LEFT JOIN tp_catalog_product_entity AS e ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY order_items.product_id HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY ordered_qty desc LIMIT 4
```

Please help me.

Comment: What does `Zend_Debug::dump($storeId);` and `Zend_Debug::dump($products->getSelect());` return?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
               ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
               ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
               ->addCategoryFilter($category)
               ->setStoreId($storeId)
               ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
               ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addOrdersCount()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description', 'description'))
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->setPageSize(4)
->setCurPage(1)
->setOrder('orders', 'desc')->load();
```

The changes are the addOrdersCount() method, and the ->setOrder() method.

Answer (score 0):

i was also face this type of issues in magento 1.6.2.
i found that there is some problem in attribute filter while i am filtering collection.

i have replace **addAttributeToFilter** with **addFieldToFilter** and it's work.

Try this may be it will be helpful for your

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the storeid for your collection. Insert this line after adding OrderedQty:

```
->setStoreId($storeId)
```